# How can I use a remote machine for swap space?

Tags: linux, remote, swap

I have two Linux boxes, one of which doesn't have much RAM or disk space. How would I go about setting up a swap file on the second machine for the first to use?

Comment: I do suspect an off board swap file is going to be *really* slow.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Not necessarily... ordinary Ethernet can sometimes be faster than an old hard disk [or 1.1 USB stick]. *(Trivia: Windows 3.11 had built-in support for swap over NetBIOS.)*

Comment: If you have an option to swap to a pen drive or a SDcard (preferably a SDcard with SLC memory) then this might be much faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have lots of choices. You can use [NBD](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/02/nbd-tutorial-network-block-device-jumpstart-guide/) a network block device. You can set up an NFS mount and [swap over it](http://www.linuxdoc.org/HOWTO/Network-boot-HOWTO/x542.html#AEN562). You can swap over CIFS.

Basically:

1. Mount a network drive.
2. Create a file on it of the appropriate size. (You can use `dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/swapfile bs=xxx count=xxx`)
3. Make that file a swap device. (Use `mkswap`.)
4. Mount it (Use `swapon`.)
5. Configure it for permanent use. (Depends on your distribution. Check `/etc/fstab`.)

Comment: Note that swap over NFS was disabled for a long time, although it's [working again in kernel 3.6](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=commit;h=a564b8f0398636ba30b07c0eaebdef7ff7837249). (The page you linked to, however, has *very* outdated instructions, including patching a 2.2 kernel...)

Comment: one more option - ATAoE :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP didn't specify hardware/software. It works on the Raspberry Pi and modern desktops. I believe swap over CIFS works on OpenWRT and most router firmwares.

Comment: hmm, or maybe iscsi swap